# Single record query based on related

Tags: soql, query, approval-process, user

I want to find a single (any) user who has an approval assigned to them.
I can't seem to find the right search term.

```
 User U = [select id from User (select actorid from processInstanceWorkItem) limit 1];
```

My goal class:

```
@isTest 
public without sharing class ApprovalsExtTEST { 

 static testMethod void TestSalesHome(){ 

 User U2 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN ( SELECT ActorId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem) LIMIT 1];


  ApexPages.StandardController stdController4 = new ApexPages.StandardController(u2); 
     UsersItemsToApprove MyController4 = new UsersItemsToApprove(stdController4); 


        System.runAs(U2) {
     MyController4.getWorkItems();   
     }

     }


     }
```

Currently errors:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join). I have also seen it called an `inner-join sub-select`. In this case, you need:

```
SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT ActorId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem
) LIMIT 1
```

Note that tests do not have access to org data by default. You will have to actually submit a test record for approval in order to get this query to return records.

```
static testMethod void demoTestItems()
{
    SomeObject__c record = new SomeObject__c();
    insert record;

    Test.startTest();
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest submitRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        submitRequest.setObjectId(record.Id);
        Approval.process(submitRequest);
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertNotEquals(0, [SELECT count() FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem]);
    system.assertNotEquals(0, [SELECT count() FROM User WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT ActorId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem
    )];
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I am getting an error of System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject when I know there are active approvals in the org

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. Maybe a permissions issue? Can you try running the code `without sharing`?

Comment: updated with more info

Comment: @jaw999 There aren't any approvals yet in your test unless you use `@SeeAllData=true`.

Comment: @jaw999 -- to avoid `seealldata=true` or forcing via apex records into an approval process; you can use a Separation of Concerns Selector layer and mock via sobjects / `json.deserialize`

Comment: Understood. Either I create the approval processes and items in the test or I use see all data and pass. thanks